# ¿Qué quiere decir "cuez"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, significado, arcaísmos

En el Diccionario de la lengua, en el artículo [**callar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6pebbaT) se recoge la expresión

> **calla y cuez**
>   1. expr. U. para recomendar a alguien que atienda al trabajo útil sin perder el tiempo en cosas fútiles.

Sin embargo, el diccionario no tiene una entrada para **cuez**, ni los diccionarios anteriores consultados por medio del NTLLE. En el CORDE solo aparece 13 veces;  todas ellas parecen formas del verbo **cocer** como en

> ... quando el agua se **cuez** con carne o con pescado ...

Únicamente aparece un caso análogo, del Libro de refranes, de Pedro Vallés (1549):

> 770. **Calla / cuez**.

Lo que me plantea ¿cuál es el significado de **cuez**, y cómo una palabra / expresión tan (aparentemente) poco utilizadas están en el diccionario?

Comment: Pues parece una corrupción de "cuece" (sobre todo a la vista del segundo ejemplo). "Calla y cuece" como podría decir "Calla y friega" o "calla y dale a la pala" o  "calla y trabaja" en general, o incluso "calla y come". La verdad es que yo siempre los escuché "al revés": "Come y calla",  o "XYZ y calla". Básicamente: deja de protestar y haz la tarea encomendada.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque la z terminal recuerda a los imperatives franceses, el dicho no aparece existir en tal idioma (sí encontré un [sólo ejemplo](http://revista.consumer.es/web/ca/20131201/salud/77659.php) en catalán).

Creo que el dicho resulta de una sencilla abreviación. [El mismo cambio afectó a los imperativos *haz*, *satisfaz*, y *sal*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_DSXCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT88&ots=fQreC62yFk&dq=imperativos%20con%20z%20haz&pg=PT88#v=onepage&q&f=false). Ya vemos que el segundo verbo es *cocer* y que *callar* se muestra en forma familiar. "Calla y cuece" sería la forma convencional de la frase idiomática.

Su significado se enfoca en lo importante y explicitamente cesa de discutir. Quitarle una sílaba no necesitada es justamente lo que manda a hacerse. En comparación con "calla y cuece", aunque contiene dos rimas, a mí me parece que "calla y cuez" tiene más fuerza enfatizante. En cuanto a lo que quiere decir, es mejor dicho así.

Comment: Siendo una frase hecha, podría venir directamente de estas épocas cuando la pérdida de esta *-e* era normal no solo en los mandatos sino también en el presente del indicativo (esta pérdida era algo más común en el portugués —dícese hoy *produz* o *traz*— y más en el asturiano donde hoy es corriente y obligatorio en la conjugación del indicativo—*cuez, suel, cos, sal*, etc).

Comment: @guifa gracias, si tuviese una referencia que muestre que el español antiguamente usaba una forma así, mejoraría la respuesta que puse. ¿eso pasaba solamente con verbos -er?

Answer (score 1):

*Cuez* es una conjugación antigua/dialectal de *cocer*:

> Calla, cuez
>   *Cuez* es una forma anticuada del actual *cuece*.

- [*Un viejo maestro de lengua: el refranero*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pHu0DgAAQBAJ&pg=PA251&dq=cuez) (2017)

Aparece en otras refranes antiguas:

> Antes cuez que hiervas

- [*Seniloquium: Refranes que dizen los viejos*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4rIsSFfBAh8C&dq=cuez&q=cuez&q=cuez)  (p.63)

Y esta forma aún existe en asturiano (ref. *cocer*, [*Diccionario General de la Lengua Asturiana*](https://mas.lne.es/diccionario/palabra/12464)).